# Ginkgo package testing

Tags: go, ginkgo

I'm implementing test suite for brand new go app and decided to use [ginkgo](http://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/%20ginkgo). The app has main function and several packages

```
.
|- main.go
|- types
|  |-- user.go
|  |-- post.go
|- server_pkg 
|  |-- users_controller.go
|  |-- posts_controller.go
|- worker_pkg
|  |-- users_worker.go
|  |-- posts_worker.go
```

I ran `ginkgo bootstrap` in each package folder and added test files using `ginkgo generate`. Now I'm able to run tests for each package separately i.e.
`cd server_pkg; ginkgo`

The question is that: how to configure my application to run all tests for main function and packages using single command?

I can chain commands like `ginkgo; cd server_pkg; ginkgo ...`, but it does not look like good solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ginkgo but if you run `ginkgo -r` in your root catalog it should run all tests. `-r` option is described in documentation as `will recursively find and run all spec suites in the current directory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run all test suits you should run this in command in your root catalog

`ginkgo -r`

Also is good practice as in normal test suits to run all test with race detector, also you could shuffle some test. You can run all this option by using

`ginkgo -r --race --randomizeAllSpecs --randomizeSuites`

Answer (score 1):

@ttomalak thank you! It's exactly what I wanted

`$ ginkgo -r`
[image]